# Saving regex into Redux store?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

How to save regex into `Redux` store?

**Example:**

I have regex saved in object:

```
const regexes = {
   name: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/
}
```

After saving this object into redux store regex is lost (parsed to empty object):

```
// Dispatch
dispatch(setRegexes(regexes))
// Redux Dev Tools:
{
   name: {}
}
```

Regex is ok even when received as payload into reducer:

```
// Reducer
case 'SET_REGEXES':
   console.log(payload.regexes) // {name: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/}
   return {...store, regexes: payload.regexes}
break;
```

This means that payload is likely `stringified` to JSON and **regex is lost**.

does this have some workaround? Or I am not supposed to save regexes into redux even technically saving regexes into JavaScript object is valid.

**EDIT: I am trying to achieve situation where I do not need to use `new RegExp(store.regexes.name)`** I want to save actual regex into store because store is JavaScript object.

Comment: This might be an interesting read in this context https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state

Comment: Could it be that it's the Redux Dev tools that's seralizing the object? I suspect the RegExp object is correctly stored in your state.

Comment: @JamieDixon You are right!

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, this sounds like a Redux Dev Tools issue and not a Redux issue.

The Dev Tools are probably serialising the data before logging to the console but the RegExp object itself should be correctly stored in your state.

Whether or not you want to store non-serialisable data in your state will be based on your own context and requirements.

As per the Redux documentation:

> It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects,
>   arrays, and primitives into your store. It's technically possible to
>   insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break
>   the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store, as well
>   as interfere with time-travel debugging.
>
> If you are okay with things like persistence and time-travel debugging
>   potentially not working as intended, then you are totally welcome to
>   put non-serializable items into your Redux store. Ultimately, it's
>   your application, and how you implement it is up to you. As with many
>   other things about Redux, just be sure you understand what tradeoffs
>   are involved.

Source: https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the RegExp to string first via its `source` property

```
case 'SET_REGEXES':
   const regexsrc = regexes.name.source;
   return {...store, regexes: {name: regexsrc}}
break;
```

Or run a loop converting each property if `regexes` is actually an array.

Then just do `new RegExp(str)` for retrieval.

Comment: I want to archieve situation where I do not need to use `new RegExp(store.regexes.name)`

Comment: But why? You also may want to add that criteria to your question @Baterka

Answer (score 0):

Just convert regex to string

```
// Reducer
case 'SET_REGEXES':
   console.log(payload.regexes) // {name: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/}
   return {...store, regexes: payload.regexes.name.toString()} // Convert to string
break;
```

```js
const regexp1 = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/
console.log(regexp1.toString())
```

Comment: Sure, but then I need to convert it back to `new RegExp(store.regexes.name)`

Comment: Yes, because regex is complex type